# Obtaining Suboptimal Solutions with Benders in GAMS

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gams-math, discrete-optimization

I have the following Benders code for a maximization problem on GAMS. It happens that sometimes GAMS give an suboptimal solution even though it should find the exact solution, since no heuristics exist and Benders tolerance (BdTol= Upper Bound - Lower Bound) is 0. I ensure that both the subproblem and the master problem are solved to optimality and optcr and optca values are taken as 0, too. I realized it as follows: for a dataset I solved the problem without enforcing any variable to take any value, and it provided an objective value. Then, I enforced a variable to take a certain value, and it provided a higher objective value. Shouldn't GAMS find the highest possible value automatically as it is a maximization problem? Do you think there is something wrong with the code?

```
Sets
i   /1*100/
j   /1*10/;

Parameters
p /4/
m /1/
BdTol /0/;

Table a(i,j) DATA;

Table b(i,j) DATA;

variables
q 'cut set variable'
z;

binary variables
y(j)
x(i,j);

positive variables
w(j);

scalar UB 'upperbound' /INF/;
scalar LB 'lowerbound' /-INF/;

set iter /iter1*iter1000000/;

set cutset(iter) 'dynamic set';
cutset(iter)=no;

variable z0 'relaxed master objective variable'
q 'cut set variable';

parameters
cutcoeff(iter,i,j);

*---------------------------------------------------------------------
* Benders Algorithm
*---------------------------------------------------------------------
loop(iter$((abs(UB-LB)> BdTol)),
         option lp=CPLEX, optcr=0, optca=0, reslim=1000000, iterlim=1000000;
         solve subproblem maximizing z using lp;
         abort$(subproblem.modelstat>=2) "Subproblem not solved to optimality";
         cutset(iter) = yes;
         cutcoeff(iter,i,j) = b(i,j)*w.l(j);
         option mip=CPLEX, optcr=0, optca=0, reslim=1000000, iterlim=1000000;
         solve master maximizing z0 using mip;
         abort$(master.modelstat>=2) "Masterproblem not solved to optimality";
         UB = min(UB, sum((i,j),a(i,j)*x.l(i,j))+q.l);
         LB = max(LB, sum((i,j),a(i,j)*x.l(i,j))+z.l);
         display x.l, y.l, z0.l, w.l, UB, LB;
);
```

Since I believe the problem is related to the algorithm, I only share that part.

Edit: New information are added.

What really interesting is, it finds suboptimal solutions only for some instances, not all the time.

The runs for a dataset is given below. The upper ones does not involve any enforcing constraints for a variable to take a certain value. The lower one involves a single variable to take a specific value.

[image]

The following is the log output for the one without the enforced variable.

```
IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :         -12.203660

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.895
--- benders3.gms(358) 88 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter1
---   4,107 rows  4,016 columns  9,820 non-zeroes
---   1,010 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.902

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3387 rows and 3387 columns.
Reduced MIP has 720 rows, 629 columns, and 1867 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 629 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.00 sec.  Objective = 0.0000
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 719.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           362.425771
Iteration:   129   Dual objective     =            96.848559
Iteration:   198   Dual objective     =            94.968744
Root relaxation solution time =    0.00 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                            0.0000                    249     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       93.1164       93.1164      249    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.00 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.00
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4107 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           93.116376    (249 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            93.116376    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          93.116376
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.954
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter2
---   12 rows  11 columns  25 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.959

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :          -2.121247

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.974
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter2
---   4,108 rows  4,016 columns  9,863 non-zeroes
---   1,010 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.982

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3354 rows and 3354 columns.
Reduced MIP has 754 rows, 662 columns, and 2034 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 754 rows, 662 columns, and 2034 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.09 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.09 sec.  Objective = -13.6132
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 751.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           365.039800
Iteration:   141   Dual objective     =            96.728338
Iteration:   211   Dual objective     =            94.098252
Root relaxation solution time =    0.01 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                          -13.6132                    246     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       93.0748       93.0748      246    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.11 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.01
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.01 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4108 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           93.074808    (246 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            93.074808    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          93.074808
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:05.115
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter3
---   12 rows  11 columns  25 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:05.120

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :          -2.847644

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:05.132
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter3
---   4,109 rows  4,016 columns  9,967 non-zeroes
---   1,010 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:05.141

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3354 rows and 3354 columns.
Reduced MIP has 755 rows, 662 columns, and 2105 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 755 rows, 662 columns, and 2105 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.00 sec.  Objective = -32.0161
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 751.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           346.636915
Iteration:   142   Dual objective     =            96.564506
Iteration:   214   Dual objective     =            93.644333
Root relaxation solution time =    0.02 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                          -32.0161                    252     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       92.6192       92.6192      252    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.09 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.09
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.09 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4109 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.01 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           92.619154    (252 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            92.619154    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          92.619154
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:05.283
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter4
---   12 rows  11 columns  24 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:05.290

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :           0.000000

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:05.304
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter4
---   4,110 rows  4,016 columns  10,038 non-zeroes
---   1,010 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:05.311

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3355 rows and 3354 columns.
Reduced MIP has 755 rows, 662 columns, and 2105 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.02 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 755 rows, 662 columns, and 2105 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 661 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.09 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.09 sec.  Objective = -32.0161
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 751.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           346.636915
Iteration:   142   Dual objective     =            96.564506
Iteration:   214   Dual objective     =            93.644333
Root relaxation solution time =    0.00 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                          -32.0161                    252     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       92.6192       92.6192      252    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.09 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.02
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.02 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4110 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           92.619154    (252 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            92.619154    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          92.619154
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:05.434
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
*** Status: Normal completion
--- Job benders3.gms Stop 12/10/22 14:37:01 elapsed 0:00:05.481
```

The following is the log output for the one with the enforced variable.

```
--- benders3.gms(151) 86 Mb
--- Starting execution: elapsed 0:00:04.400
--- benders3.gms(358) 88 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 88 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter1
---   12 rows  11 columns  31 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.406

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :         -12.203660

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.417
--- benders3.gms(358) 88 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter1
---   4,107 rows  4,016 columns  9,820 non-zeroes
---   1,009 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.425

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3547 rows and 3500 columns.
Reduced MIP has 560 rows, 516 columns, and 1458 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 516 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 1 rows and 1 columns.
Aggregator did 1 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 558 rows, 514 columns, and 1454 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 514 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.01 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.01 sec.  Objective = 25.1590
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 557.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           213.565458
Iteration:    77   Dual objective     =            96.476340
Iteration:   150   Dual objective     =            93.814763
Root relaxation solution time =    0.00 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                           25.1590                    193     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       93.1164       93.1164      193    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.01 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.00
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4107 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           93.116376    (193 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            93.116376    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          93.116376
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.551
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter2
---   12 rows  11 columns  25 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.555

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :          -2.121247

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.568
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter2
---   4,108 rows  4,016 columns  9,863 non-zeroes
---   1,009 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.576

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3460 rows and 3413 columns.
Reduced MIP has 648 rows, 603 columns, and 1781 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 602 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 648 rows, 603 columns, and 1781 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 602 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.00 sec.  Objective = -2.6132
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 645.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           339.579984
Iteration:   130   Dual objective     =            96.654157
Iteration:   208   Dual objective     =            93.001859
Root relaxation solution time =    0.09 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                           -2.6132                    213     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       92.8258       92.8258      213    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.09 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.09
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.09 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4108 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           92.825775    (213 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            92.825775    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          92.825775
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.703
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating LP model subproblem
--- benders3.gms(360) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter3
---   12 rows  11 columns  24 non-zeroes
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.707

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 12 rows and 11 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
LP status(1): optimal

Optimal solution found.
Objective :           0.000000

--- Reading solution for model subproblem
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.720
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
--- Generating MIP model master
--- benders3.gms(367) 89 Mb
--- LOOPS iter = iter3
---   4,109 rows  4,016 columns  9,901 non-zeroes
---   1,009 discrete-columns
--- Executing CPLEX: elapsed 0:00:04.727

IBM ILOG CPLEX   Jul  4, 2012 23.9.5 WEX 36376.36401 WEI x86_64/MS Windows
--- GAMS/Cplex licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.4.0.1

Reading data...
Starting Cplex...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 3461 rows and 3413 columns.
Reduced MIP has 648 rows, 603 columns, and 1781 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 602 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Probing time =    0.01 sec.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 648 rows, 603 columns, and 1781 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 602 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time =    0.09 sec.
Found feasible solution after 0.09 sec.  Objective = -2.6132
Probing time =    0.00 sec.
Clique table members: 645.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Initializing dual steep norms . . .

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Dual objective     =           339.579984
Iteration:   130   Dual objective     =            96.654157
Iteration:   208   Dual objective     =            93.001859
Root relaxation solution time =    0.00 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                           -2.6132                    213     --- 
*     0     0      integral     0       92.8258       92.8258      213    0.00%
Elapsed real time =   0.11 sec. (tree size =  0.00 MB, solutions = 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.02
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.02 sec.
MIP status(101): integer optimal solution
Fixing integer variables, and solving final LP...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 4109 rows and 4016 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time =    0.00 sec.
Fixed MIP status(1): optimal

Proven optimal solution.

MIP Solution:           92.825775    (213 iterations, 0 nodes)
Final Solve:            92.825775    (0 iterations)

Best possible:          92.825775
Absolute gap:            0.000000
Relative gap:            0.000000

--- Reading solution for model master
--- Executing after solve: elapsed 0:00:04.861
--- benders3.gms(358) 89 Mb
*** Status: Normal completion
--- Job benders3.gms Stop 12/10/22 14:25:56 elapsed 0:00:04.910
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the data or seeing the log. Could be a numerical issue. How does the "Range statistics" look like (GAMS prints this to the log, right before the solver starts)? Is there any message/warning from the solver? How does your model terminate? With one of your abort statements? Because you ran out of iterations? Or because UB became equal to LB?

Comment: @Lutz thank you so much for your message. I was not able respond quickly, sorry about that. The model terminates when UB becomes equal to LB. I added a representative solution of iterations and the log information about both cases to the main post. Would be so glad if you could take a look.

Comment: OK, it starts to differ as of iter2 for the master problem. I guess it would make sense to compare the two versions of that model solved isolated and check if there is anything one can learn from the difference (is it just the variable that was fixed which should not improve the solution according to your post, or is there more?). Sorry, that I can not give a more precise conclusion here. ps: It seems that the GAMS version you use it 10 years old. If you think, it might be a problem in GAMS, upgrading to a new version might help.